# datastax solr doesn't work after enabling in datastax

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax

I am done datastax instruction for enabling solr (DSE search) and configuring with cassandra line by line from below documentation but solr still not working, I mean can't reach http://localhost:8983 via browser or curl.

**[datastax docs for enabling solr (DSE search)](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchTutCreatTab.html)**

I am try to reloading cassandra with solr (command: `sudo dse cassandra -s`
) but this exception happens after run command:

```
ERROR 01:47:29,998  Error starting local jmx server: 
java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 7199; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:341) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:249) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:411) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:212) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.setup(RegistryImpl.java:152) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.<init>(RegistryImpl.java:112) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(LocateRegistry.java:239) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.maybeInitJmx(CassandraDaemon.java:100) [cassandra-all-2.1.14.1272.jar:2.1.14.1272]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:222) [cassandra-all-2.1.14.1272.jar:2.1.14.1272]
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:345) [dse-core-4.8.7.jar:4.8.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:564) [cassandra-all-2.1.14.1272.jar:2.1.14.1272]
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:74) [dse-core-4.8.7.jar:4.8.7]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at javax.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(ServerSocketFactory.java:231) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.RMIServerSocketFactoryImpl.createServerSocket(RMIServerSocketFactoryImpl.java:13) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.14.1272.jar:2.1.14.1272]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:666) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:330) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
ERROR 01:47:30,044  Fatal exception during initialization
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Cannot start node if snitch's data center (Solr) differs from previous data center (Cassandra). Please fix the snitch configuration, decommission and rebootstrap this node or use the flag -Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true.
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.checkHealth(SystemKeyspace.java:629) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.14.1272.jar:2.1.14.1272]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:290) [cassandra-all-2.1.14.1272.jar:2.1.14.1272]
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:345) [dse-core-4.8.7.jar:4.8.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:564) [cassandra-all-2.1.14.1272.jar:2.1.14.1272]
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:74) [dse-core-4.8.7.jar:4.8.7]
INFO  01:47:30,045  DSE shutting down...
INFO  01:47:30,045  All plugins are stopped.
May 27, 2016 1:47:30 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8983
ERROR 01:47:30,076  Exception in thread Thread[Daemon shutdown,5,main]
java.lang.AssertionError: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.addLocalApplicationStateInternal(Gossiper.java:1415) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.14.1272.jar:2.1.14.1272]
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.addLocalApplicationStates(Gossiper.java:1439) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.14.1272.jar:2.1.14.1272]
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.addLocalApplicationState(Gossiper.java:1429) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.14.1272.jar:2.1.14.1272]
    at com.datastax.bdp.gms.DseState.setActiveStatusSync(DseState.java:252) ~[dse-core-4.8.7.jar:4.8.7]
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.preStop(DseDaemon.java:437) ~[dse-core-4.8.7.jar:4.8.7]
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.safeStop(DseDaemon.java:447) ~[dse-core-4.8.7.jar:4.8.7]
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon$1.run(DseDaemon.java:697) ~[dse-core-4.8.7.jar:4.8.7]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
May 27, 2016 1:47:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Solr
INFO  01:47:31,057  Shutting down Solr audit logging filter
16/05/27 01:47:31 INFO audit.SolrHttpAuditLogFilter: Shutting down com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.RepeatablePOSTQueryFilter filter
May 27, 2016 1:47:31 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/solr] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 27, 2016 1:47:31 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/solr] appears to have started a thread named [NonPeriodicTasks:1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 27, 2016 1:47:31 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8983
```

**ps aux | grep cassandra output:**

```
nasser   14515  0.0  0.0  19772  2720 pts/14   S+   02:45   0:00 grep --color=auto cassandra
root     32456  1.0 29.3 5242616 3553776 pts/14 SLl 00:39   1:17 /usr/bin/java -Ddse.system_memory_in_mb=11829 -Dcassandra.config.loader=com.datastax.bdp.config.DseConfigurationLoader -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms2957M -Xmx2957M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss256k -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:-UseBiasedLocking -XX:StringTableSize=1000003 -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:+ResizeTLAB -XX:CompileCommandFile=/etc/dse/cassandra/hotspot_compiler -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=7199 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml -Dcassandra.logdir=/var/log/cassandra -Dcassandra.storagedir= -cp :/usr/share/dse/dse-core-4.8.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/dse-hadoop-4.8.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/dse-hive-4.8.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/dse-search-4.8.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/dse-spark-4.8.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/dse-sqoop-4.8.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/antlr-3.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/antlr-runtime-3.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M24.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-asn1-ber-1.0.0-M24.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-i18n-1.0.0-M24.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-ldap-client-api-1.0.0-M24.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-ldap-codec-core-1.0.0-M24.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-ldap-codec-standalone-1.0.0-M24.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-ldap-extras-codec-1.0.0-M24.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-ldap-extras-codec-api-1.0.0-M24.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-ldap-model-1.0.0-M24.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-ldap-net-mina-1.0.0-M24.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/api-util-1.0.0-M24.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/asm-5.0.3.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-codec-1.9.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-compiler-2.6.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/commons-pool-1.6.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/guava-16.0.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/guice-multibindings-3.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/HdrHistogram-1.2.1.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/jackson-core-2.2.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/janino-2.6.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/javassist-3.18.2-GA.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/java-uuid-generator-3.1.3.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/jbcrypt-0.4d.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.10.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/jline-1.0.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/journalio-1.4.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/jsr305-2.0.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/kmip-1.7.1e.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/log4j-1.2.13.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/mina-core-2.0.7.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/reflections-0.9.10.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/stringtemplate-3.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/common/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/etc/dse:/etc/dse/cassandra:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/tools/lib/stress.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/antlr-3.5.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/cassandra-all-2.1.14.1272.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/cassandra-clientutil-2.1.14.1272.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/cassandra-thrift-2.1.14.1272.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/commons-math3-3.2.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/disruptor-3.0.1.jar:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you didn't stop the already running process. Can you check if you have another cassandra process running (dse in your case)?

Comment: I am going to stop dse befor running `dse cassandra -s` and running again but still not working.

Comment: why datastax is unstable in run?!  every changes in config or every operation can terminate `dse` or `cqlsh`

Comment: I'm running DSE in production without any issues. I would need more informations to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: `dse cassandra-stop` telling me: Unable to find DSE process, please use -p if you are sure it's running.  but I am sure dse is running.

Comment: What is the output of ps aux | grep cassandra?

Comment: can you help me with team-viewer to find out problem and share with others?

Comment: question edited and `ps aux | grep cassandra` output added.

Comment: I think Matija should know the answer. I would like to know the answer!

Answer (score 0):

This issue has nothing to do with the search functionality in DSE Search. Cassandra is tring to come up but something is bound to the jmx port 7199.

You can find out what is bound to that port with 'netstat -a | grep 7199'. However, most likely you have an existing instance of dse running already.

```
sudo pkill -f dse
```

Will kill the dse process. Then you can try starting it again.